# Create expandable varlist

Tags: matrix, stata, stata-macros

I tried to convert two data files into a matrix in Stata.

In the first data file there are only `10` columns, so I used:

```
mkmat d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10, matrix(dataname)
```

However, the second data file contains more than `100` columns.

Do I have to manually include in `mkmat` all variable names, or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Condo_programmer my answer provides a direct solution to your question. Please consider upvoting/accepting it if you think it is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear
set obs 5

forvalues i = 1 / 5 {
    generate d`i' = rnormal()
}

list

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |        d1          d2          d3          d4          d5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  .2347558     .255076   -1.309553    1.202226   -1.188903 |
  2. |  .1994864    .5560354   -.7548561    1.353276   -1.836232 |
  3. |  1.444645   -1.798258    1.189875   -.0599763    .4022007 |
  4. |  .2568011    -1.27296    .5404224   -.1167567    1.853389 |
  5. | -.4792487     .175548    1.846101    .4198408   -1.182597 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

You could simply use wildcard characters:

```
mkmat d*, matrix(d)
```

or

```
mkmat d?, matrix(d)
```

Alternatively, the commands `ds` and `unab` can be used to create a local macro containing a list of qualifying variable names, which can then be used in `mkmat`:

```
ds d*

mkmat `r(varlist)', matrix(d1)
matrix list d1

d1[5,5]
            d1          d2          d3          d4          d5
r1   .23475575   .25507599  -1.3095527   1.2022264  -1.1889035
r2   .19948645    .5560354  -.75485611   1.3532759  -1.8362321
r3   1.4446446  -1.7982582   1.1898755   -.0599763    .4022007
r4   .25680107  -1.2729601   .54042244  -.11675671   1.8533887
r5  -.47924873     .175548    1.846101   .41984081  -1.1825972
```

```
unab varlist : d*

mkmat `varlist', matrix(d2)
matrix list d2

d2[5,5]
            d1          d2          d3          d4          d5
r1   .23475575   .25507599  -1.3095527   1.2022264  -1.1889035
r2   .19948645    .5560354  -.75485611   1.3532759  -1.8362321
r3   1.4446446  -1.7982582   1.1898755   -.0599763    .4022007
r4   .25680107  -1.2729601   .54042244  -.11675671   1.8533887
r5  -.47924873     .175548    1.846101   .41984081  -1.1825972
```

The advantage of `ds` is that it can be used to further filter results with its `has()` or `not()` options.

For example, if some of your variables are strings, `mkmat` will complain:

```
tostring d3 d5, force replace
mkmat d*, matrix(d)
string variables not allowed in varlist;
d3 is a string variable
```

However, the following will work fine:

```
ds d*, has(type numeric)
d1  d2  d4

mkmat `r(varlist)', matrix(d)

matrix list d

d[5,3]
            d1          d2          d4
r1  -1.5934615   2.1092126  -.99447298
r2  -.51445526  -.62898564   .56975317
r3  -1.8468649  -.68184066   .26716048
r4  -.02007644  -.29140079   2.2511463
r5  -.62507766    .6255222   1.0599482
```

Type `help ds` or `help unab` from Stata's command prompt for full syntax details.